# How to dynamically create Property in ical4j?

Tags: java, ical4j

Let's say I have an List of unknown length of ical properties of unknown name represented as strings, i.e.
`["DTSTART;TZID="Sarajevo, Skopje, Warsaw, Zagreb":20230726T100000", "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=SU;UNTIL=20230831T215959;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO"]`.

What is the best way to parse `String` as `ical4j` `Property`?

I considered splitting strings at colon and using `new PropertyBuilder(new DefaultPropertyFactorySupplier().get()).name(key).value(value).build()`, but this method fails when some parameters are present like `TZID` in provided example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.